# Get all history (versions) of an exchange meeting using EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using EWS API to manage the exchange meetings (create/update/delete). When I retrieve an appointment there is [AppointmentSequenceNumber](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.appointmentsequencenumber?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_Appointment_AppointmentSequenceNumber) indicating version of changed appointment in the response, is there a way to get all versions (history) of the appointment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for them in the WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsVersions folder using the uid property of the Appointment see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Holy-COW-Changes-to-Recoverable-Items-versioning-in-Exchange/ba-p/600259